# Neural network not being able to be precise enough for normalized data

Tags: neural-network

My training data without normalizing it, contains numbers in range of -2000 to 2000.
If my input from training data being 300, I normalize it:

```
1 / 300 = 0,0033~
```

So it will be a range of -1 - 1.

The problem is that difference between normalized values will be way too small.

```
1 / 300 = 0,00333~
1 / 299 = 0,00334~
```

It requires for neural network to get extreemly precise.
I'm using gradient based backpropagation algorithms while tanh being activation function. It takes way too long for neural network to get that precise.

What learning method should I use or how could I improve my current neural network for this task?
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You could use a [ReLU](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rectifier_(neural_networks)) (linear activation) activation function for the first few layers and do a tanh activation for the output layer.

```
Input (-ReLU-> Hidden L.)*n -tanh-> Output
```

Comment: Is it really a only solution?
I don't really want to use the linear activation function.

Comment: Probably not. I'm actually rather new too in this topic and I also disliked the idea of ReLU, but as long as you have enough hidden layer (>1), it works pretty good.